# How to resize cell height to Label height in CollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cell, uicollectionviewcell

I made an app with Xcode using Swift and in collectionView and collectionViewCell. I have fetched posts from my WordPress website , one category which is only text and i want to show full text on ViewController . now the problem is i am using this for cell height ..

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    var returnValue = CGSize()
    
    if (indexPath.item % 5 == 4){
        
        if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height > 960{ //Write iPhone or iPad size. If iPad :
            returnValue = CGSize(width: (((view.frame.width) - 40) / 2), height: 100)
        } else { //if iPhone
            returnValue = CGSize(width: view.frame.width-20 , height: 100)
        }
        
    } else {
        
        if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height > 960{ //Write iPhone or iPad size. If iPad :
            returnValue = CGSize(width: (((view.frame.width) - 40) / 2), height: 180)
        } else { //if iPhone
            returnValue = CGSize(width: view.frame.width-20 , height: 180)
        }
        
    }
               
    return returnValue
}
```

now when post display on ViewController than text shows just height of cell and other text is just hidden , how can i resize cell according to Label Height ?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple just calculate the height of the label (Don't forget the spacing top & bottom).

```
func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)

    return ceil(boundingBox.height)
}
```